# Why I can't call Math.Round(double,int) overload

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double

In .NET Library there is Function like
`System.Math.Round(double, int)`

But why I need to cast double value to float to make it work..??
Look on the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c. Is this what u ask for?

Comment: I had already looked on this. This is not 4 wht i m lukin 4..? @Mullaly

Comment: Is your question why there is no implicit cast from double to float?

Comment: Actually my mistake. I assumed that the error is in function calling. But that is not. It is because I m storing its returned value in float @Mullaly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following function

```
Math.Round(double value, int digits)
```

[image: Math.Round(double value, int digits) returns a double]

Returns a `double`. I see that you have tried to define a `float` of name `d` to the output from `Math.Round(n,2)` where `n` is a double of value `1.12345` and `2` represents an integer using the following code

```
double n = 1.12345;
float d = Math.Round(n,2);
```

You'll actually get an error because the output from the above function is `double` and not a `float`.

```
Cannot implictly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

You may fix this by changing `float d = Math.Round(n,2);` to `double d = Math.Round(n,2);`

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Converting from double to float, you will lose precision and it cannot be done implicitly. If you assign a float value to a double variable which is more accurate, the compiler will not complain.